# Add rounded progress line to progress bar

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to program a progress bar:

```css
.create-progress-bar {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 25px 0;
    display: flex;
}

.create-progress-bar li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
}

.create-progress-bar .step-inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.create-progress-bar li span.step-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.create-progress-bar li span.step-icon {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 18px;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}

.create-progress-bar li:first-child {
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.create-progress-bar li:nth-child(2) {
    align-items: center;
}

.create-progress-bar li:last-child {
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.create-progress-bar li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #666666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: 31px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="create-progress-bar">
    <li class="active">
        <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
            <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
            <span class="step-title">Create</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
            <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
            <span class="step-title">Check</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
            <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
            <span class="step-title">Done</span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I've the problem that I can't get the progress bars styled between each elements. It should look like this depending on the class `active` in each `li` element:

[image]

Is there someone how has an idea how to get this done?

Comment: Are you willing to change your code and structure? This seems like a ton of unnecessary code and I think I got a simpler solution for you.

Comment: Yeah sure, go for it

Comment: Alright, working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using flexbox and `:before` pseudo-elements. You can create line before every li element except the first one and if the li has active class you change border color and line color.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}

li:not(:first-child):before {
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  margin: 0 10px;
}

li.active .step-inner-wrapper {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

li.active:before {
  background: red;
}

.step-inner-wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.step-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="create-progress-bar">
  <li class="active">
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Create</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Check</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Done</span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="create-progress-bar">
  <li class="active">
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Create</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li class="active">
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Check</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li class="active">
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Check</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Check</span>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="step-inner-wrapper">
      <span class="step-icon">✔</span>
    <span class="step-title">Done</span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same problem as below. If the text length get's longer, it overflows the content or page. Thats not so good. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Mr. Jo One solution would be to limit the width of the text and add some padding to the ul https://jsfiddle.net/dc46nuLa/1/. I am not sure what kind of result is desired here.

Answer (score 1):

So I changed your CSS completely and made some minor changes to your HTML structure. This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpe1kq32/):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress-bar>li:first-child {
  width: auto;
}

.progress-bar>li:first-child .line {
  display: none;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .tick {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .line {
  background: red;
}

.progress-bar>li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.tick {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.tick>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-bar">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CREATE</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CHECK</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>DONE</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You will see that I removed the approach of using pseudo-classes, such as `::after`, and added a `div.line` instead. In CSS I removed the first progress line with `display: none` instead of removing the `div` tag because it is easier to use dynamically since you don't have to care about removing the first line when prepending content. But you can also just remove it like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wfbvsr3a/):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress-bar>li:first-child {
  width: auto;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .tick {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .line {
  background: red;
}

.progress-bar>li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.tick {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.tick>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-bar">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CREATE</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CHECK</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>DONE</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

### Edit #1

Based on the comments, here is a version with a soft hyphen:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress-bar>li:first-child {
  width: auto;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .tick {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .line {
  background: red;
}

.progress-bar>li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.tick {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.tick>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-bar">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CREATE&shy;VERY&shy;LONG&shy;TEXT</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CHECK</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>DONE</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could theoretically use `hyphens: auto`. But this has massive lack of browser support, as it can be seen [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=hyph).

If you don't want the `-` dashes just use `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress-bar>li:first-child {
  width: auto;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .tick {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.progress-bar>li.active .line {
  background: red;
}

.progress-bar>li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.tick {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.tick>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-bar">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CREATEVERYLONGTEXT</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>CHECK</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="tick">
      ✔<span>DONE</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Currently I've the problem that one of the text is a bit longer under the circle and overflows the content. Any idea?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Use soft hyphens `&shy;` or `word-wrap: break-word`.